# Cannot find graphics variable when method is called?

Tags: java, graphics, actionlistener

This is a JButton that needs to have action listener when clicked will call drawPiece method. Currently error is connect find symbol variable g.

```
JButton column3 = new JButton();
    column3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        x = 2;
        //.drawPiece(g);
        column3.drawPiece(g);


      }
    });
```

This is the drawPiece method and where the graphics are initialized.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics pen) {
    super.paintComponent(pen);
    drawBoard(pen);
    drawPiece(pen);
    boardarray();
  }

  public void drawPiece(Graphics g) {
    x = x;
    y=0;// fixed at 0
    int turn=0; 
    boolean p1Win = false;
    boolean p2Win = false;
    //while(p1Win==false && p2Win==false) {
      checkPiece();
      g.setColor(Color.RED);
      g.fillOval(10+x*110,10+y*110,100,100);
      //checkWin();     
      p1Win = true;
  }
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Currently error is cannot find symbol variable g.

Answer (score 0):

```
column3.drawPiece(g);
```

You should never invoke a painting method from a listener directly. If you want to repaint the component then you tell the component to repaint itself:

```
column3.repaint();
```

The makes a call to the `RepaintManager` to schedule the repainting. Ultimately the `paintComponent()` method will be invoked with the appropriate `Graphics` object.